# How to pull in and push out text browser?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qt-designer, pyqt5

I am using Qt designer to create a plugin in Qgis3. I want to add description of a tool beside the tool. For this I have tried using 'Text Browser' by connecting it with button. I am able to hide and display the description(A Text Browser) using following code:

```
    def hide(self):
    if self.dlg.textBrowser.isHidden()==True:
        self.dlg.textBrowser.setVisible(True)  
    else:
        self.dlg.textBrowser.hide()
    #connect the action using Push button
    self.dlg.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.hide)
```

But I want to pull in and pull out the description window. It should work like example showing below.
[image]
Is there any way to do this using Qt designer?